# how put icon in ring in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want make a wpf control like image below
[circle with hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9S6y.png)

I make circle with hole in it with this code in xaml

```
<Ellipse Width="350" Height="350" StrokeThickness="80" Fill="Transparent">
    <Ellipse.Stroke>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Gray"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Gray"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Ellipse.Stroke>
</Ellipse>
```

but I don't know how put icon in it
is there any similar component?
I want this work on different resolution and number of this icon is dynamic
so another question is how I can scale its for putting more icons
thnx

Comment: Try putting both (your elipse + a picture) in a `Grid` with no column/row.  Then you'll needto apply the proper margin to the picture to get it to line up the way you want.

Comment: Better place both `Image` and `Ellipse` inside the `Canvas` or `Grid`

Comment: You can use a Border control with a big CornerRadius

Comment: thnx @CodingGorilla and  Gopichandar but how I can find best margin dynamically when the number of icons increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="1000"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="DarkGray">
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="SomeIcon" 
                        Width="50"
                        Height="50"
                        Margin="10"
                        Background="Black"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Margin="80"
                        CornerRadius="3000"
                        Background="White"/>
            </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work out. Replace the source and path of your icon in the image tag

```
<Border CornerRadius="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Background="DarkGray" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\user-thumbnail.png" 
               Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20"/>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Height="300" Width="300" CornerRadius="150" Background="White"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```